# My Test Case is failing when I run it with Firefox Browser

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, firefox, python-behave

I have created a framework for Python using Selenium and Behave-BDD. There are 24 test cases and all are passing when it runs with Chrome, Chrome Headless, and Edge browsers but when it runs with Firefox browser and then only 1 test case fails and the rest are passing through and it shows a defect in the Smoke Test Result.

So what is the solution? Does anyone have an idea?

**Error message from Smoke Test Result as follow;**

> selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message: Didn't find
> element by xpath:
> </html/body/div[6]/div[3]/div/div/div[3]/div/div/div[1]/div/div/div/div/div/div[3]/div[2]/iframe>
> Stacktrace:
> WebDriverError@chrome://remote/content/shared/webdriver/Errors.jsm:183:5
> NoSuchElementError@chrome://remote/content/shared/webdriver/Errors.jsm:395:5
> element.find/</<@chrome://remote/content/marionette/element.js:300:16

```
 from behave import *
    from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
    import Base.Base
    from Page_Objeck_CommunitiesPage import CommunitiesPage
    from Utilities.customLogger import LogGen
    

    @then("search the community name")
    def step_impl(context):
    global cDiscussionPage
    cDiscussionPage = CommunitiesPage(context.driver)
    cDiscussionPage.clickSearchCommunityName()
    Base.Base.wait_for_seconds(8) 
    enter code here

@then("check if the search results shows in the community table")
def step_impl(context):
    assert True


@then("click on search result")
def step_impl(context):
    cDiscussionPage.clickMyCommunitiesTable()


@then("check if the page navigated to selected community")
def step_impl(context):
    cDiscussionPage.checkLabelTitleSummary()


@then("click on Discussions")
def step_impl(context):
    cDiscussionPage.clickDiscussions()


@then("check if the discussions page is displayed")
def step_impl(context):
    cDiscussionPage.checkTitleDiscussions()


@then("click on add icon to add the discussion group")
def step_impl(context):
    cDiscussionPage.clickAddIconOnDiscussions()
    cDiscussionPage.clickAddDiscussionGroup()


@then("add discussion group by name and save")
def step_impl(context):
    cDiscussionPage.addDiscussionGroupName()
    cDiscussionPage.clickSaveOnDiscussionGroup()


@then("click on add icon and choose discussion")
def step_imp(context):
    cDiscussionPage.clickAddIconOnDiscussions()
    cDiscussionPage.clickDiscussionOnAddIcon()


@then("choose the discussion group and click on add discussion")
def step_impl(context):
    Base.Base.wait_for_seconds(8) 
    cDiscussionPage.clickNewlyCreatedDiscussionGroup()


@then("give title and message")
def step_impl(context):
    cDiscussionPage.addTitleOnAddDiscussion()


@then("click on Save and Publish on add discussion")
def step_impl(context):
    cDiscussionPage.clickSaveOnAddDiscussion()


@then("click on the discussion and validate comment button")
def step_impl(context):
    cDiscussionPage.clickDiscussionToComment()


@then("click on comment and add response message and save")
def step_impl(context):
    cDiscussionPage.clickOnComment()
    Base.Base.wait_for_seconds(5) 
    iframe = context.driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "iframe.gwt-RichTextArea")
    context.driver.switch_to.frame(iframe)
    cDiscussionPage.addMessageOnAddResponse()
    context.driver.switch_to.parent_frame()
    Base.Base.wait_for_seconds(5)   
    cDiscussionPage.clickSaveOnAddResponse()


@then("check if the comment is showing successfully in the comments pan")
def step_impl(context):
    cDiscussionPage.checkCommentInCommentPan()
```

Comment: Always post your code and error messages in text format in the body of your posts, not as images. Images make it difficult to efficiently assist you as they cannot be copied and offer poor usability as they cannot be searched. See: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/15497888)

Comment: Please provide the code, at least of the test. Moreover the print screen is pointing on Chrome as a webdriver, not Firefox as you suggested.